# TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Layer' for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is in connection with my other [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264676/networkx-read-shp-works-on-python-2-7-but-not-on-python-3) in GIS stackexchange.

Why does TypeError gets raised in Python 3 when in fact the same code being run in Python 2 gets executed with no errors?

**Code:**

```
net = nx.DiGraph()
print(path)
shp = ogr.Open(path)
for lyr in shp:
    print (type(lyr))
    print (lyr)
    fields = [x.GetName() for x in lyr.schema]
    print (lyr.schema)
    print(fields)
    for f in lyr:
        print(f)
```

**Error**

> File "/home/gridlockdev/Desktop/heroku/grace/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/nx_shp.py", line 81, in read_shp
>       for f in lyr:
>   TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Layer'

Comment: Speak with `NetworkX` devlopers, it's a bug (or a feature) on their end.

Answer (score 0):

import networkx as nx
**author** = """Ben Reilly (benwreilly@gmail.com)"""
**all** = ['read_shp', 'write_shp']

[docs]def read_shp(path, simplify=True):
    """Generates a networkx.DiGraph from shapefiles. Point geometries are
    translated into nodes, lines into edges. Coordinate tuples are used as
    keys. Attributes are preserved, line geometries are simplified into start
    and end coordinates. Accepts a single shapefile or directory of many
    shapefiles.

```
"The Esri Shapefile or simply a shapefile is a popular geospatial vector
data format for geographic information systems software [1]_."

Parameters
----------
path : file or string
   File, directory, or filename to read.

simplify:  bool
    If ``True``, simplify line geometries to start and end coordinates.
    If ``False``, and line feature geometry has multiple segments, the 
    non-geometric attributes for that feature will be repeated for each 
    edge comprising that feature.

Returns
-------
G : NetworkX graph

Examples
--------
>>> G=nx.read_shp('test.shp') # doctest: +SKIP

References
----------
.. [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile
"""
try:
    from osgeo import ogr
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError("read_shp requires OGR: http://www.gdal.org/")

if not isinstance(path, str):
    return

net = nx.DiGraph()
shp = ogr.Open(path)
for lyr in shp:
    fields = [x.GetName() for x in lyr.schema]
    for f in lyr:
        flddata = [f.GetField(f.GetFieldIndex(x)) for x in fields]
        g = f.geometry()
        attributes = dict(zip(fields, flddata))
        attributes["ShpName"] = lyr.GetName()
        if g.GetGeometryType() == 1:  # point
            net.add_node((g.GetPoint_2D(0)), attributes)
        if g.GetGeometryType() == 2:  # linestring
            last = g.GetPointCount() - 1
            if simplify:
                attributes["Wkb"] = g.ExportToWkb()
                attributes["Wkt"] = g.ExportToWkt()
                attributes["Json"] = g.ExportToJson()
                net.add_edge(g.GetPoint_2D(0), g.GetPoint_2D(last), attributes)
            else:
                # separate out each segment as individual edge
                for i in range(last):
                    pt1 = g.GetPoint_2D(i)
                    pt2 = g.GetPoint_2D(i + 1)
                    segment = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
                    segment.AddPoint_2D(pt1[0], pt1[1])
                    segment.AddPoint_2D(pt2[0], pt2[1])
                    attributes["Wkb"] = segment.ExportToWkb()
                    attributes["Wkt"] = segment.ExportToWkt()
                    attributes["Json"] = segment.ExportToJson()
                    net.add_edge(pt1, pt2, attributes)

return net
```

Comment: Proper formatting and some explanation would be useful here.